# Lernen bei jdm. vs Lernen mit jdm

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

I want to say that it was very interesting with you(my teacher) to learn German.  What is the difference? What's better and right?
My option - Es war sehr interessant, (bei dir)/(mit dir) Deutsch zu lernen.

P.S. Ich duze meine Lehrerin.

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit different from English, where all the following cases would translate into "with":

If you learn something "mit jemandem" - *Both* are learning, that is, you learn "*together* with someone", probably both at the same level of knowledge.

In case you learn something "bei jemandem" - *One* is learning, one is teaching (case #1, apparently your case), or you are both learning, but one together with the other at the other's place (case #2).

Apparently, you want to say

> Es war sehr interessant, *bei dir* Deutsch zu lernen.

And, to make things a bit more complicated, you could even say

> Es war sehr interessant, *von* dir Deutsch zu lernen.

The last one, however, somewhat implies that you have been taught *everything* and the matter is exhausted.

Comment: -1, denn »Tschüss Mutti, ich lerne **bei** Lisa und bin um fünf wieder daheim« bedeutet nicht, dass Lisa die Sprecherin unterrichtet. Es bedeutet, dass die Sprecherin sich zu Lisa hin bewegt, und am Ziel dann zu lernen. Ohne weiteren Kontext würde ich bei diesem Beispiel vermuten, dass die Sprecherin und Lisa Klassenkameradinnen sind, die miteinander lernen wollen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dann hast du meinen Beitrag nicht richtig gelesen, denn genau *der* Fall ist beschrieben: "one together with the other at the other's place (case #2)". Lies nochmal. Und: Schüler sagen durchaus "Ich lerne Englisch bei Herrn Müller", obwohl sie noch nie bei ihm zuhause waren.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty easy: **"bei dir"** is referring to the location **"mit dir"** is referring to the person. So if you were happy to learn "with her" - which I would assume - you would use **"mit dir"**. If you were happy to study with her at her new place then you would use **"bei dir"**... Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

- > Ich lerne **bei** dir.
  >   Ich lerne **bei** dir Deutsch.

  Ich gehe oder fahre zu dir nach Hause, zu deinem Arbeitsplatz oder an einen anderen Ort an dem du gewohnheitsmäßig anzutreffen bist. Dort, an diesem Ort lerne ich.

  Es ist sehr wahrscheinlich, dass ich mich zu dir begebe, um dort *mit* oder *von* dir zu lernen, aber »*bei* dir lernen« macht eigentlich nur eine Aussage über den Ort. Diese Formulierung liefert keinen Anhaltspunkt über unser gegenseitiges Verhältnis beim Lernen, oder ob du überhaupt an meinem Lern-Vorgang involviert bist wenn ich bei dir lerne.
- > Ich lerne **mit** dir.
  >   Ich lerne **mit** dir Deutsch.

  Hier wird nichts darüber ausgesagt, wo gelernt wird. Das kann bei dir, bei mir oder auch irgendwo anders sein.

  Aber diese Formulierung lässt erkennen, dass wir beide gemeinsam lernen, und uns dabei gegenseitig, also auf gleichem Niveau, helfen. Zwei (oder mehrere) Schüler derselben Klasse lernen *mit* einander.

  Dabei könnte auch ein Lehrer anwesend sein, der dabei aber nicht unterrichtet, sondern die gemeinsam lernenden Schüler höchstens anleitet. Üblicherweise geht man aber davon aus, dann kein Lehrer anwesend ist, wenn eine Personen **mit** einer anderen lernt.
- > Ich lerne **von** dir.
  >   Ich lerne **von** dir Deutsch.

  Wieder erhalten wir keine Information über den Ort. Aber hier ist klar, dass ich weniger kann oder weis als du, und dass ich versuche, diesen Unterschied auszugleichen. Ob du auch aktiv etwas dazu beiträgst, dass ich etwas lerne, bleibt bei dieser Formulierung offen.

  Du könntest ein Lehrer sein, der mich aktiv unterrichtet, indem du mir etwas erklärst, oder mir etwas zeigt, und mich bei Fehlern korrigierst.

  Du könntest aber auch eines meiner Vorbilder sein, das gar nichts davon weis, dass ich versuche mir deine Fertigkeiten anzueignen. Wenn ich Tanzen lernen wollte, und du ein berühmter Tänzer wärst, könnte ich mir Filme ansehen, in denen ich deinen Tanz beobachte und analysiere, um später deine Bewegungen zu imitieren. Auch in diesem Fall lerne ich *von* dir, aber ohne deine aktive Unterstützung, und möglicherweise sogar ohne dass du es bemerkst.

---

Ergänzungen:

- > Du lehrst mich.
  >   Du lehrst mich Deutsch.

  Hier wir eindeutig deine aktive Rolle thematisiert. Du tust etwas, damit ich später etwas kann was ich vorher nicht konnte. Natürlich liegt es in der Natur der Sache, dass auch ich etwas dazu beitragen muss, aber aus dieser Formulierung geht klar hervor, dass du aktiv bist. Du erklärst oder zeigst mir etwas, und du hilfst mir wenn ich Fehler mache.
- > Du unterrichtest mich.
  >   Du unterrichtest mich in Deutsch.
  >   Du unterrichtest mich in Fach Deutsch.

  Gleiche Bedeutung wie zuvor. Beachte, dass »in« oder »im Fach« verwendet werden muss, wenn gleichzeitig der Unterrichtsgegenstand genannt werden soll.
- > Du bringst mir Deutsch bei.

  Auch das bedeutet dasselbe wie die beiden vorherigen Beispiele, allerdings ist man hier gezwungen, das Fach anzugeben. »*Du bringst mir bei*« wäre falsch.